# How to set bounty? sufficient rep but no link

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

At the time I asked this question ([Is an ACPI GPE storm normal in an Ubuntu session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149028/is-an-acpi-gpe-storm-normal-in-an-ubuntu-session)) I didn't have enough rep. Now I do and I want to set a bounty, but there's no link.

The link states "question eligible for bounty Jun 12 at 16:28". If I click that, it gives me the FAQ, but no way to actually set one.

Is there no way to set a bounty? Do I have to ask it all over again?

I don't have any other bounties running at the moment, for other questions I do have the option to set a bounty.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I can bounty this for you if you want (though I don't know why it's not bountying for you)

Comment: That would be very nice if you would, but that doesn't solve the issue for others. As I said, I can always ask again. I'll wait and see for the moment (btw edited the question)

Comment: Just saw you 'bountied' it... Thank you very much